# UTF-8 encoding not working with Eclipse java application

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, locale

I've got a little encoding problem somewhere that I can't fix.

I've got the next java file:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("áéíàèì€aei");
    }
}
```

The file charset encoding is UTF-8 and I'm using Eclipse over Windows to edit and compile it. After having the file compiled I move the .class file to a Debian server, whose charset encoding is also UTF-8, as it's shown here:

```
root@srv-dev:~# locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

and when i run the app i'm getting:

```
root@srv-dev:~# java Main
Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã Ã¨Ã¬â¬aei
```

I'm Eclipse, I've set UTF-8 as project encoding by left-clicking in properties and going to resources/text file encoding / Other : UTF-8.

I can't see what else I would change. There's something I might be missing but I can't find it.

Comment: How are you executing the command on debian - is it via SSH? If so, perhaps your SSH client isn't UTF-8 friendly.

Comment: ouch! Yeah, it's ssh. Maybe that's the problem but I'm not sure as I'm getting the accents when executing queries agaist the mysql database that's also running on the server. I mean: "mysql> select libelle from echeance where libelle like '% Exécution - Echéance Mois Mo + 1%';"
+----------------------------------------------------+
| libelle                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Tranche  2 - Exécution - Echéance mois Mo + 10     |
| TC 2 - Exécution - Echéance Mois Mo + 10  65%x2/12 |
..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to the putty configuration. It set the remote charset as ISO-8859-1.

And I'm guessing the reason why mysql query result showed the accents was because it's also using ISO-8859-1 charset. To configure putty, just follow the next link:

[Configuring PuTTY to use UTF-8](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.fr/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html)

To change encoding permanently, just follow this answer -that you'll actually find in the link's comments, but I don't want you to miss it so here it is:

> "In order to make these changes permanent in Putty, you open up Putty,
>   make the changes you want to save, then click back on the Session
>   window, click on the "Default Settings" under Saved Sessions, and then
>   click on Save. Next time you open Putty whatever you changed prior to
>   clicking save will still be in effect."

Comment: Had you cared to tell in your question you were using putty, you'd instantly have an answer. Precision is important in those matters.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The thing is I dind't expect Putty to be the problem, as it showed every character I typed. That's why I didn't mention it. But it's also true it's important to give every detail.

Answer (score 1):

The console/shell you are using to run your java file also need to be UTF-8 encoding enabled otherwise characters will not be displayed properly. Follow the steps mentioned on the below link to enable UTF-8 on debian shell:

http://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/set-up-a-debian-linux-machine-to-handle-utf-8-in-a-shell-or-console-app/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In fact, the shell is showing those characters:    "root@srv-dev:~# áéíóúuàèìù" <<-- copy-paste from shell

Comment: @user1453418 Have u tried to compile and run the file on debian?

Comment: No. I haven't. And it's because i'm kinda trying to reduce a bigger problem I have. There's a developper who need to use Eclipse@windows to code an app and after he needs to deploy it over this Debian server. I just have to set up the enviroment and I've just found this java encoding problem.

Comment: Thanks again Juned. Apparently it's all set up correctly. root@srv-dev:~#  locale charmap
UTF-8